# How do you pass a variable by reference within Start-Job?

Tags: powershell, parameters, pass-by-reference

How do you modify a variable within `Start-Job`?  This code outputs `0`, seemingly because the variable is passed by value:

```
$vara = "0"

$j = start-job -ScriptBlock {
   $args[0] = "1"
} -ArgumentList $vara

wait-job $j > $null
receive-job $j

Write-Host $vara  ## => "0"
```

How do you pass the parameter by reference (hence, outputting `1`)?

Comment: I thought i knew, but none of what i know is working. one very inefficient way would be to save the variables into a file, and then pull them from the file. Jobs are inside their own version of powershell, and that's why it gets tricky. I tried global, local, private, script etc.. none seem to pass it back to the script.

Comment: @RobertCotterman Yes, also thought of using a file. But we could hope Microsoft implemented such a basic case of pass-by-ref...

Comment: i think you want "synchronized variables". take a look at this article ... Sharing Variables and Live Objects Between PowerShell Runspaces | Learn Powershell | Achieve More — https://learn-powershell.net/2013/04/19/sharing-variables-and-live-objects-between-powershell-runspaces/

Comment: @Lee_Dailey does this actually let you sync variables between a parent and child session? In such a way that you can actually modify parent variables through runspaces? I thought it was for syncing variables across multiple children. For instance perhaps you spawned 100 jobs and wanted the environment to be the same.

Comment: @JacobColvin - from what little i understand of all that, yes. look at this quote from the linked article ... "I also added the parent host runspace into the child runspace so I can use the WriteVerboseLine() method to write the values to the parent session." ///// unfortunately, i _do not_ understand what is actually happening. it looks to me like it does what the OP seems to want.

Answer (score 4):

You're completely out of scope when modifying anything inside a job. Nothing will just magically populate in your current session.

You could do something like this:

```
$vara = "0"

$j = start-job -ScriptBlock {
   "1"
} -ArgumentList $vara

wait-job $j > $null
$vara = receive-job $j

Write-Host $vara
```

And if you need to populate a lot of arguments, you can do something like this:

```
$vara = "0"

$j = start-job -ScriptBlock {
   [pscustomobject]@{
      vara1 = "1"
      vara2 = "0"
    }
} -ArgumentList $vara

wait-job $j > $null
$vara = receive-job $j

Write-Host $vara.vara1
```

Comment: This is a good workaround. +1 But this trick of playing with only return value, could be less usable for complicated algorithms inside the job. Or for parallelism and modifying values before job ending. Is there no passing-by-ref mechanism?

Comment: Well, you can use the `$using:` scope, but you can't set those variables. In general, you should always be assembling output using my method 2. It's just best practice anyway.